# Cron Job variable not accessible

Tags: variables, cron

I am currently running a cron job on my cPanel to update a variable containing exchange rates, how can I make this variable available to functions and pages in my wordpress site?

**My command in cPanel for cron job running every minute:**

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/cronjob.php
```

**cronjob.php**

```
<?php
require('wp-blog-header.php');
$exchangeRates = getExchangeRates();

function getExchangeRates(){
// etc etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's best not to include `wp-blog-header.php`. Instead, set the cron job to your homepage URL with a `?mycustomcron=true` variable appended (eg: `http://example.com/?mycustomcron=true`. Then we will check for the existance of this variable when the page loads:

```
function wpse_103127_check_cron() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['mycustomcron'] ) ) {

        // things to do on cron here

        exit; // no need to load the page on cron
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_103127_check_cron' );
```

As for saving the data for later access in WordPress, you can save the data to the `wp_options` table:

```
$exchange_rates = getExchangeRates();
update_option( 'exchange_rates', $exchange_rates );
```

And then access it later:

```
$exchange_rates = get_option( 'exchange_rates' );
```

See the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) Codex article for more information about saving data to the database.